# R/python - Web-scraping information with rvest and/or BeautifulSoup returns (sometimes) no results

Tags: python, r, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, rvest

I am web-scraping restaurants information (e.g. names, addresses) from different websites. I generally use two main methods: the functions in the `rvest()` package (`R`), and the ones in the `BeautifulSoup` module (`python`). I manage to collect information most of the time (when R fails, generally python works) but sometimes, after reading the webpage, I can't find the information in the nodes I select. Here are two websites that give this behaviour:

Australia: https://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=restaurant&locationClue=All+States&pageNumber=2&referredBy=www.yellowpages.com.au&&eventType=pagination

Tunisia: http://www.pagesjaunes.com.tn/List?page=2

And here's the R code I use to access the restaurants' names (example is for just one page):

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

# AUSTRALIA
webpage <- read_html(x = "https://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=restaurant&locationClue=All+States&pageNumber=2&referredBy=www.yellowpages.com.au&&eventType=pagination")

webpage_name <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes("a.listing-name") %>% 
  html_text(trim = TRUE)

webpage_name

# TUNISIA
webpage <- read_html(x = "http://www.pagesjaunes.com.tn/List?page=2")

webpage_name <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes("div.result-info-block") %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  html_text(trim = TRUE)

webpage_name
```

As you can see, the `webpage_name` object is empty. With python the result doesn't change:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# AUSTRIALIA
webpage = requests.get("https://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=restaurant&locationClue=All+States&pageNumber=2&referredBy=www.yellowpages.com.au&&eventType=pagination")
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")
soup_names = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "listing-name"})

print(soup_names)

# TUNISIA
webpage = requests.get("www.pagesjaunes.com.tn/List?page=2")
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")
soup_names = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "result-info-block"})

print(soup_names)
```

For the case of Tunisia, I think the problem is that the URL doesn't change for the category I select, but appears just "List?page=2" for every category after the main URL. **But then why I can display the list of information in the website?**

For the Australian page, I really have no clue of what is going on. These are the method I generally use for every website, but sometimes I encounter these problems.

Do you have any idea on how to proceed? Thank you!

Comment: Australia gives me what likely is 71 restaurant names. Tunisia gives me nothing. Also in chrome I don't see anything in Tunisia, so the R behaviour is likely correct.

Comment: Hey Sirius thanks for your answer. I'm sorry, did you run the same code? Because when I do it I get nothing. Please have a look at the screenshot [here](https://i.imgur.com/Hj3XgGQ.png). How is this possible?

Comment: Yeah, I get 71 names. I pasted the html I get here: https://controlc.com/56d964fc  ( pasted the file I got from `cat( toString( webpage ), file="~/foo.html" )`

Comment: Hey, I am not quite getting what you did. I mean the precise steps, because if I paste that string in R I got  a NULL value. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: I just saved my html to a file and uploaded it to a pstaebin so you can have a look at it. See how it differ from the html you get. maybe regional settings makes it serve different content to different visitors